# Not getting jquery Ajax data using dynamic id selector

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My PHP code looks like this -

```
for ($i=0;$i<=10;$i++) {
    ?>
<div id="">
    <input type="text" id="GetCommentText-<?php echo $i;?>"></input>
    <input type="hidden" id="GetPostID-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $i;?>">
    <button type="button" id="SelectPostComment-<?php echo $i;?>" >Submit</Submit>
</div>
<?php
}
?>  
<div id="ShowAjaxesult"></div>
```

I want to get the data of these `<input>` elements using jquery dynamic id selectors. My jQuery looks like -

```
           <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
               $("[id^=SelectPostComment-]").click(function(){
                   var $td = $(this).closest('input').next();
                   var CommentText = $td.find("[id^=GetCommentText-]").val();
                    var PostID = $td.find("[id^=GetPostID-]").val();

                   $.ajax( {
                      type : 'GET',
                      url:'test1.php',
                      data : {CommentText: CommentText, PostID: PostID},
                      success:function(data) {

                         $('#ShowAjaxesult').html(data);
                      }
                   });
               });
            });
            </script>
```

But I'm not getting value of ajax data `CommentText` and `PostID` in my `test1.php` file when i click `<button>`. Not sure what mistake I'm making. Please help.

Comment: Open your console, do you have any errors? Your selector doesn't handle event delegation either, you'd need to use `.on` for that.

Comment: You have some invalid syntax -> `</input>` after `<input type="text" id="GetCommentText-<?php echo $i;?>"></input>`, `</Submit>` to close `<button type="button" id="SelectPostComment-<?php echo $i;?>" > Submit</Submit>`. Are these copy/paste errors?

Comment: @Fred I'm getting this error - 'event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead' in console.

Comment: Um... why am I being called out? I made an edit, not a comment.

Comment: Try changing `var $td = $(this).closest('input').next();` to `var $td = $(this).parent();` http://jsfiddle.net/5Gp7x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
for ($i=0;$i<=10;$i++) {
?>
    <div id="">
    <input type="text" id="GetCommentText-<?php echo $i;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="GetPostID-<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $i;?>">
    <button type="button" id="SelectPostComment-<?php echo $i;?>" >Submit</button>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
<div id="ShowAjaxesult"></div>
```

and js part:

```
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('[id^="SelectPostComment-"]').click(function(){  // changed here
               var $td = $(this).parent();  // changed here
               var CommentText = $td.find('[id^="GetCommentText-"]:first').val();  // changed here
                var PostID = $td.find('[id^="GetPostID-"]:first').val();  // changed here

               $.ajax( {
                  type : 'GET',
                  url:'test1.php',
                  data : {CommentText: CommentText, PostID: PostID},
                  success:function(data) {

                     $('#ShowAjaxesult').html(data);
                  }
               });
           });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: It worked for me. Well, do we really need to use :first because this is working without using :first in js part.

Comment: I always write selectors more concrete, so that's why I use :first to avoid unnecessary walking by DOM tree if I really need 1 element (:first or :last) (:

Answer (score 0):

Or You could use more efficient way (no need to make garbages in DOM Tree):

```
<?php
for ($i=0;$i<=10;$i++) {
    ?>
    <div data-postId="<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="commentText" value="" />
    <button type="button" class="submit-comment">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
<div id="ShowAjaxesult"></div>
```

and js part:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.submit-comment').click(function(){  
           var $parent = $(this).parent(); 
           var postId = $parent.data('postId');
           var commentText = $parent.find('input[name="commentText"]:first').val();
           $.ajax( {
              type : 'GET',
              url:'test1.php',
              data : {CommentText: commentText, PostID: postId},
              success:function(data) {
                 $('#ShowAjaxesult').html(data);
              }
           });
       });
    });
    </script>
```